# Adding fields to user registration in Mediawiki

Tags: php, wiki, mediawiki

I've been Googling a lot, but I just can't figure out how to add a couple fields to user registration. By default Mediawiki only asks for username, password and real name. I noticed that form is a template under /includes/templates/UserLogin.php, but I don't want to modify that file to make the changes.

What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved, http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CustomUserCreateForm helped a lot.. :)